# No horizontal centering in multirow at \newline

Tags: tables, multirow

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
 \begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}
                |>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.4cm}|}\hline
X & Y \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{No problem} & One Line \\ \cline{2-1} 
                            & Two Line \\ \hline
\multirow{5}{*}{Problem} & One Line \\ \cline{2-1} 
                         & 1 \newline 2 \newline 3 \newline 4\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

and displaying

[image].

Only last row (4) is centered. 1, 2, and 3 not center. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you are:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
 \begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}
                |>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.4cm}|}\hline
X & Y \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{No problem} & One Line \\ \cline{2-1} 
                            & Two Line \\ \hline
\multirow{5}{*}{Problem} & One Line \\ \cline{2-1} 
                         & \hfil1 \newline \null\hfil 2 \newline\null\hfil 3 \newline 4\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

`\hfil` corrects additional horizontal space added by `\newline`, `\null` is a horizontal box with zero width.

[image]

Comment: Perfect working, @Przemysław Scherwent

Answer (score 4):

This is the problem with `m` type column when it appears at the end (i.e., as the last column). You can add an empty column at the end and things are on track again.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
 \begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}
                |>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.4cm}|@{}c@{}}\hline
X & Y \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{No problem} & One Line &\\ \cline{2-1}
                            & Two Line &\\ \hline
\multirow{5}{*}{Problem} & One Line &\\ \cline{2-1}
                         & 1 & \\
                         & 2 & \\
                         & 3 & \\
                         & 4 &\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect working, too. @Harish Kumar

Answer (score 2):

I slightly simplify the code using the `makecell` package, which allows for line breaks in cells and a common formatting. There is also a `Xhline` command for `\hline`s of variable thickness:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow, array, makecell}

 \begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{!{\vrule width1pt}% >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.4cm}!{\vrule width1pt}}
  \Xhline{1pt}
  X & Y \\
  \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{No problem} & One Line \\
  \cline{2-1}
                              & Two Line \\ \hline
  \multirow{5}{*}{Problem} & One Line \\
  \cline{2-1}
                              & \makecell{1 \\2 \\ 3 \\ 4}\\
  \Xhline{1pt}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]